# react error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, authentication

I switched up my backend database, created a new superuser, and then did yarn start to go into the dev environment for react. only to now get this error

**VM4135:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse ()**

I believe the issue is that I am pulling a web token and the user data at once. then storing them in local storage, but since there is nothing in local storage since this is a fresh boot, it's looking for the token that isn't there? I'm not too sure if that's correct but I can't seem to get past it.

any help would be appreciated.

profile page that's throwing up the error.

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user") || {});
const Profile = () => (
  <div className={s.root}>
    <h1 className="page-title">
      User - <span className="fw-semi-bold">Profile</span>
    </h1>
      ...
```

token and user auth action

```
// token and user auth
export function receiveToken(payload) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const user = payload.user;
    const token = payload.token;

    delete user.id;
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
    dispatch(receiveLogin());
  };
}
```

full error

```
VM4135:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Module../src/pages/profile/Profile.js (Profile.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Module../src/components/Layout/Layout.js (InputValidation.js:72)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Module../src/components/App.js (useraccounts.js:44)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Module../src/index.js (a6.jpg:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Object.1 (theme.scss?2910:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: Can you also provide what `localStorage.getItem("user")` returns? It's likely invalid. Given the error, it likely starts with an `o`. For example, `JSON.parse("o")` will throw the same error

Comment: it returns null, I havent logged anyone in, so there's nothing to pull from, yarn start just launches with nothing and the error in the console

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the first line. You can't `parse` a valid JavaScript Object. Change your line to:

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || {};
```

Here's an example from console.

[image: console]

Also, check the contents of `localStorage.getItem("user")`. What if, it stored something as `[object Object]`? So when you're setting the local storage item, make sure you do:

```
const user = {some: "obj"};
localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(user));
```

Comment: so that worked and i was able to get in but now that I'm logged in, the profile page with `const user = localStorage.getItem("user")` is not loading the user data

Comment: "You can't parse a valid JSON" - I don't understand this... do you mean "object"?

Comment: @Ebolasudan What have you got inside in the `user` now? Is it a string or object.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman hey sorry, the data is being set into local storage with localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user)); so if i were to pull it up on redux tools it shows up like "{"name":"John Doe","last_login":null,"is_superuser":false,"email":"johndoe3@gmail.com","is_active":true,"is_staff":false,"user_type":6,"groups":[],"user_permissions":[]}"